# Replacing accented characters with javascript

Tags: javascript, non-ascii-characters

On onkeyup, i want to replace accented characters to non-accented. With this code now, i didnt get nothing. If i dont give the `this.value` to the function, i get an error for the `split`.

I want to use this function for more input with onkeyup, but always for that input, what i am writing in.

```
<input onKeyUp="RemoveAccents(this.value);" type="text" required name="termek_seo" class="product-name" value="<?php echo isset($_POST["termek_seo"])?$_POST["termek_seo"]:""; ?>" />



    function RemoveAccents(strAccents) 
{
    var strAccents = strAccents.split('');
    var strAccentsOut = new Array();
    var strAccentsLen = strAccents.length;
    var accents = 'ÀÁÂÃÄÅàáâãäåÒÓÔÕÕÖØòóôõöøÈÉÊËèéêëðÇçÐÌÍÎÏìíîïÙÚÛÜùúûüÑñŠšŸÿýŽž';
    var accentsOut = "AAAAAAaaaaaaOOOOOOOooooooEEEEeeeeeCcDIIIIiiiiUUUUuuuuNnSsYyyZz";
    for (var y = 0; y < strAccentsLen; y++) 
    {
        if (accents.indexOf(strAccents[y]) != -1) 
        {
            strAccentsOut[y] = accentsOut.substr(accents.indexOf(strAccents[y]), 1);
        }
        else
        {
            strAccentsOut[y] = strAccents[y];
        }
    }
    strAccentsOut = strAccentsOut.join('');
    return strAccentsOut;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

How can i write the tolowercase in this code?

```
function RemoveAccents(s) 
{
    var i = 'ÀÁÂÃÄÅàáâãäåÒÓÔÕÕÖŐòóôõöőÈÉÊËèéêëðÇçÐÌÍÎÏìíîïÙÚÛÜŰùúûüűÑñŠšŸÿýŽž'.split('');
    var o = 'AAAAAAaaaaaaOOOOOOOooooooEEEEeeeeeCcDIIIIiiiiUUUUUuuuuuNnSsYyyZz'.split('');
    var map = {};
    i.forEach(function(el, idx) {map[el] = o[idx]});
    return s.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9]/g, function(ch) { return map[ch] || ch; })
}
```

Comment: It just works... :]

Comment: Works?? Where? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ive solve the problem with an another code:

```
function RemoveAccents(s) 
{
    var i = 'ĂĂĂĂĂĂĂ ĂĄĂ˘ĂŁĂ¤ĂĽĂĂĂĂĂĂĹĂ˛ĂłĂ´ĂľĂśĹĂĂĂĂĂ¨ĂŠĂŞĂŤĂ°ĂĂ§ĂĂĂĂĂĂŹĂ­ĂŽĂŻĂĂĂĂĹ°ĂšĂşĂťĂźĹąĂĂąĹ ĹĄĹ¸ĂżĂ˝Ĺ˝Ĺž+_.:;[]()/*"<> '.split('');
    var o = 'AAAAAAaaaaaaOOOOOOOooooooEEEEeeeeeCcDIIIIiiiiUUUUUuuuuuNnSsYyyZz---------------'.split('');
    var map = {};
    i.forEach(function(el, idx) {map[el] = o[idx]});
    return s.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9]/g, function(ch) { return map[ch] || ch; }).toLowerCase();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It just works...

```js
function RemoveAccents(strAccents) {
  var strAccents = strAccents.split('');
  var strAccentsOut = new Array();
  var strAccentsLen = strAccents.length;
  var accents = 'ÀÁÂÃÄÅàáâãäåÒÓÔÕÕÖØòóôõöøÈÉÊËèéêëðÇçÐÌÍÎÏìíîïÙÚÛÜùúûüÑñŠšŸÿýŽž';
  var accentsOut = "AAAAAAaaaaaaOOOOOOOooooooEEEEeeeeeCcDIIIIiiiiUUUUuuuuNnSsYyyZz";
  for (var y = 0; y < strAccentsLen; y++) {
    if (accents.indexOf(strAccents[y]) != -1) {
      strAccentsOut[y] = accentsOut.substr(accents.indexOf(strAccents[y]), 1);
    } else {
      strAccentsOut[y] = strAccents[y];
    }
  }
  strAccentsOut = strAccentsOut.join('');
  console.log(strAccentsOut);
  return strAccentsOut;
}
```

```html
<input onKeyUp="RemoveAccents(this.value);" type="text" required name="termek_seo" class="product-name" value="ÀÁÂÃÄÅàáâãäåÒÓÔÕÕÖØòóôõöøÈÉÊËèéêëðÇçÐÌÍÎÏìíîïÙÚÛÜùúûüÑñŠšŸÿýŽž" />
```

Comment: But why doens it work for me? I see your fiddle, that works.

Comment: just use native `toLowerCase`

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.